# How can I import a csv file into the google cloud sql service (opposed to importing a sql dump)

Tags: sql, cloud

How can I import csv files into the google cloud sql service (opposed to importing a sql dump)?

Can I in some way use the squirrel client?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just started using Google Cloud SQL. I connected to my instance with the MySQL Workbench. I created my first table, but then I wanted to import a CSV file into that table, and it was not clear on how to do that from MySQL Workbench. So, here are the steps to do this (thanks Aimon Bustardo):

1. Convert your CSV file to a SQL file using this site (there are other options to convert to SQL, but this is an easy service): http://csv2sql.com/
2. From MySQL Workbench Navigator for the MySQL instance, click "Data Import/Restore"
3. Click "Import from Self-Contained File" and then select the SQL file created in Step 1.
4. Click "Start Import" and your data is uploaded to the Cloud!

Answer (score 1):

Converting it to SQL is your best be until they have a csv importer. There are command line utilities or online services. One of which that is free: http://csv2sql.com/